# Custom Gulp.js plugin: TypeError "Path must be a string. Received undefined"

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-plugin

I've found several threads on StackOverflow about `TypeError: Path must be a string`, even though I've not been able to apply the suggested solutions to my very case.

I'm trying to build a Gulp plugin that connects to the (paid) javascriptobfuscator.com service and use their `POST` API to obfuscate my JS.

The Gulp task looks like:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    jso = require('./jsobfuscator');

gulp.task('jso', function() {
    // .jsx contain extendscript language, which as far as 
    // the service is concerned, could be treated as .js
    return gulp.src('.src/app/jsx/photoshop.jsx')
               .pipe(jso())
               .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
});
```

The `jsobfuscator.js` file contains the following code:

```js
var through = require('through2'),
    http = require('http'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    Readable = require('stream').Readable

module.exports = function() {
  /**
   * @this {Transform}
   */

    var transform = function(file, encoding, callback) {

        var that = this;

        var proj = {};
        proj.APIKey = "/* MyAPIKey*/";
        proj.APIPwd = "/* MyAPIPwd*/";
        proj.Name = "DoubleUSM";
        proj.ReorderCode = true;
        proj.ReplaceNames = true;
        proj.EncodeStrings = true;
        proj.MoveStrings = true;
        proj.MoveMembers = true;
        proj.DeepObfuscate = true;
        proj.SelfCompression = true;
        // Unsure about these two...
        proj.CompressionRatio = "Auto";
        proj.OptimizationMode = "Auto";

        var appJS = new Object();
        appJS.FileName = "app.js";
        appJS.FileCode = file.contents.toString('utf8');
        // Will try to implement multiple files later on
        proj.Items = [appJS];

        var postData = JSON.stringify(proj);

        // Length is OK
        gutil.log ("Length: " + Buffer.byteLength(postData, 'utf-8'))

        var options = {
            host: 'service.javascriptobfuscator.com',
            path: '/HttpApi.ashx',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'text/json',
                'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData, 'utf-8')
            }
        };

        callback = function(response) {
            response.setEncoding('utf8');

            var str = '';
            response.on('data', function(chunk) {
                str += chunk;
            });

            response.on('end', function() {
                // I get the correct response here!
                gutil.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(str), null, '  '));

                var resObj = JSON.parse(str);
                // Converting the received string into a Buffer
                var fileStream = new Readable();
                // resObj.Items[0].FileCode is where the obfuscated code belongs
                fileStream.push(resObj.Items[0].FileCode);
                fileStream.push(null);
                that.push(fileStream);
                callback();
            });
        }

        var req = http.request(options, callback);
        req.write(postData);
        req.end();
    };

    return through.obj(transform);
};
```

When I run the gulp task I apparently get the proper response from the javascriptobfuscator code (as you can see below) yet there's something wrong in the part where I pass along the file to the destination because I'm getting:

```
(master)*  gulp jso
[15:13:30] Using gulpfile ~/Dropbox/Developer/PROJECTS/DOUBLE USM/gulpfile.js
[15:13:30] Starting 'jso'...
[15:13:31] Lenght: 21897
[15:13:32] {
  "Type": "Succeed",
  "Items": [
    {
      "FileName": "app.js",
      "FileCode": /* ... Long, horrible, properly obfuscated blob here... */
    }
  ],
  "ErrorCode": null,
  "Message": null,
  "FileName": null,
  "LineNumber": null,
  "ExceptionToString": null
}
path.js:7
    throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));
    ^

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.resolve (path.js:1146:7)
    at DestroyableTransform.saveFile [as _transform] (/Users/davidebarranca/Dropbox/Developer/PROJECTS/DOUBLE USM/node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/dest/index.js:36:26)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/Users/davidebarranca/Dropbox/Developer/PROJECTS/DOUBLE USM/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/Users/davidebarranca/Dropbox/Developer/PROJECTS/DOUBLE USM/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:12)
    at doWrite (/Users/davidebarranca/Dropbox/Developer/PROJECTS/DOUBLE USM/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:237:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (/Users/davidebarranca/Dropbox/Developer/PROJECTS/DOUBLE USM/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:227:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/Users/davidebarranca/Dropbox/Developer/PROJECTS/DOUBLE USM/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:194:11)
    at DestroyableTransform.ondata (/Users/davidebarranca/Dropbox/Developer/PROJECTS/DOUBLE USM/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:546:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
```

Admittedly I'm not an expert of Gulp plugins – I'm trying to build a functionality for my own private use. It looks like I'm quite close, but I've been stuck in this dead end for a while and I need help from more experienced ones.

Thanks in advance

---

### Half-working update

Modifying the `response.on('end')` callback as follows, I've been able to finally write the file:

```
response.on('end', function() {

    var resObj = JSON.parse(str);

    var fileStream = new Readable();
    fileStream.push(resObj.Items[0].FileCode);
    fileStream.push(null);

    // Manually creating a new Vinyl file
    var jsFile = new Vinyl({
        cwd: file.cwd,
        base: file.base,
        path: file.path,
        contents: fileStream
    });

    return that.push(jsFile);
    // callback();
});
```

I had to comment out the final `callback()`, though, otherwise I would have run into an error pointing to the `response.setEncoding('utf8');` line, being `response` undefined.

The problem is now that it seems like **the task**, in some way, **never terminates**. The console says `Starting 'jso'...`, the file is written, the console returns, but there's no `Finished 'jso' after nn ms`, and worst of all, I'm completely **unable to chain more gulp tasks afterwards**, so if I:

```js
gulp.task('jso1', function() {
    return gulp.src('.src/app/jsx/photoshop.jsx')
               .pipe(jso())
               .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
});

gulp.task('jso2', ['jso1'], function() {
    return gulp.src('.src/app/app.js')
               .pipe(jso())
               .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
});

// then in the Terminal:
$ gulp jso2
```

The only thing that I get is `jso1` starting, apparently working, but never finishing; `jso2` never runs.

---

Answer (score 0):

Many hours of head scratching made me get to the answer. Briefly, in  my Gulp plugin:

1. I had to **return a new Vinyl file** in the the `response.on('end')` callback: the file's `contents` property needs to be the stream from the server response.
2. My half-working solution's main flaw is that I've given the **same name (`callback`) to two very different functions**. One is the `callback` from the initial `transform` function; the other one is the `http.request` callback. Commenting out the last `callback()` call, after `return that.push(jsFile);` prevented the whole Gulp task from ending.

The full working code is as follows:

```
var through  = require('through2'),
    http     = require('http'),
    gutil    = require('gulp-util'),
    Readable = require('stream').Readable,
    Vinyl    = require('vinyl');

module.exports = function() {

    var transform = function(file, encoding, callback) {

        if (file.isNull()) { return callback(null, file) }

        var that = this;

        var proj = {};
        proj.APIKey = "/* MyAPIKey */";
        proj.APIPwd = "/* APIPwd */";
        proj.Name = "Project";
        proj.ReorderCode = true;
        proj.ReplaceNames = true;
        proj.EncodeStrings = true;
        proj.MoveStrings = true;
        proj.MoveMembers = true;
        proj.DeepObfuscate = true;
        proj.SelfCompression = true;
        proj.CompressionRatio = "Auto";
        proj.OptimizationMode = "Auto";

        var appJS = new Object();
        appJS.FileName = "app.js";
        appJS.FileCode = file.contents.toString('utf8');

        proj.Items = [appJS];

        var postData = JSON.stringify(proj);

        var options = {
            host: 'service.javascriptobfuscator.com',
            path: '/HttpApi.ashx',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'text/json',
                'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData, 'utf-8')
            }
        };

        /* Renamed to avoid confusion with transform's callback */
        postCallback = function(response) {

            response.setEncoding('utf8');
            var str = '';
            response.on('data', function(chunk) {
                str += chunk;
            });

            response.on('end', function() {

                var resObj = JSON.parse(str);
                var fileStream = new Readable();
                fileStream.push(resObj.Items[0].FileCode);
                fileStream.push(null);

                /* Return a new Vinyl File */
                var jsFile = new Vinyl({
                    cwd: file.cwd,
                    base: file.base,
                    path: file.path,
                    contents: fileStream
                });

                that.push(jsFile);
                callback();
            });
        }

        var req = http.request(options, postCallback);
        req.write(postData);
        req.end();

    };

    return through.obj(transform);
};
```

Perhaps there might be better ways to return the Vinyl file without creating a new one.

Another improvement would be to group all the source files and make a single http call to javascriptobfuscator API (it is possible in fact to add multiple files to the `proj.Items` array), but I have no idea how to group files in the source, pass them all at once to the Gulp plugin, and then split them back later.